# I want to display only first 3 letters of city in caps and not remaining letters in sql.ex mumbai become MUM

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I am trying to display only the first three letters of a city name in all caps. For example, "mumbai" should display as "MUM" and "pune" should display as "PUN". I attempted to use the `upper` function, but it only converts the entire string to uppercase. Can someone suggest a query to accomplish this? If possible, can you also provide an explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Use the combination of the SUBSTRING and UPPER functions in your SQL query.

For example -

```
SELECT UPPER(SUBSTRING(city_name, 1, 3)) AS selected_city FROM cities;
```

Comment: Could you please explain your query? Why 1,3? And as a from?

Comment: The city_name is the column name 1 is the first char and 3 is the last char for ex in Mumbai Mum. a is just an alias u can name that as anything will edit the answer as selected_city.